# Blackberry COD files randomly missing when using Eclipse 3.5

Tags: blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I'm finding the BB/Eclipse environment incredibly unstable and wanted to know if I'm doing something fundamentally wrong here?

I build my project and it produces about 40 or so COD files... usually.  Sometimes if I clean and run some COD files are missing and it fails to run (or worse it runs the old version somehow).  I kid you not, I'm spending about an hour each time I want to run/test my setup which is an order of magnitude slower than the other platforms I work with.  It eventually works by hitting the clean/debug/clean/debug/etc... and doing nothing else except these clean/debug/repeat steps.

If I make incremental changes to my src it's fairly reliable at picking them up but when I add a new resource via windows explorer and say 'refresh' on that directory in eclipse it's when all the problems start.

Any pointers from experienced Eclipse/BB users would be much appreciated (especially how to narrow down why sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't).
Thanks,
Stuart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I've narrowed down the issues.  Firstly I use DropBox on the src but this has the inadvertent feature of backing up build files and can't find a way of disabling this. 
If the files are locked by Dropbox it unsurprisingly fails, the catch is it doesn't say 'couldn't write to file as it's locked' or anything helpful like that... just fails.  Obviously when I go to inspect it Dropbox has done it's stuff so the perfect crime!

My learnings:

1. disable Dropbox on COD producing builds.
2. When changing SDK version I found I have to 
   change the SDK via the build config settings, 
   clean, 
   exit eclipse, 
   delete the build directory with windows explorer,
   Restart eclipse and hit refresh/clean.

That seems to build fairly reliably now.  Without restarting Eclipse I get all sorts of wierd errors of files going to wrong locations and dirty data being picked up.  The main one is any //#ifdef's are not picked up by the preprocessor correctly so get 1001 errors.